# Updating Duplicate Data From Last Row to First Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Table name : Customer

```
| CID | First | Last | RandomNumber |
|  1  |   J   |  T   |     432      |
|  2  |   J   |  T   |     432      |
|  3  |   J   |  T   |     432      |
|  4  |   J   |  T   |     100      |
|  5  |   S   |  A   |     432      |
|  6  |   S   |  A   |     432      |
|  7  |   S   |  A   |     200      |
```

I have a table with about 500 rows and I want to update the first duplicate row with the data that is in the last duplicate row. In the end, the first row should have the random number of 100. I want to be able to do this for any duplicates within the table.

Thank you.

Comment: what have you tried so far? do you have something that's almost or partially working?

Comment: can u give expected  output

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it. I assume by duplicates you meant the combination of first,last. First create a cte that ranks each row within the duplicates so that you know which is first and which is last. Then use the cte to join the first row to the last row and update.

I would test this just to make sure. I did it against your sample data and it works.

```
;with cte AS
(
SELECT 
    *
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FIRST, LAST ORDER BY CID) AS Rnk
FROM Customers
)

-- This will show you what will be updated
SELECT cte1.cid, cte1.first, cte1.last, cte1.RandomNumber, cte2.RandomNumber
FROM cte cte1
JOIN (SELECT first, last, max(rnk) as MaxRnk FROM cte GROUP BY first, last) a 
ON a.first = cte1.first and a.last = cte1.last and cte1.rnk = 1
JOIN cte cte2 on cte1.first = cte2.first and cte1.last = cte2.last and cte2.rnk = a.maxrnk


-- The update
UPDATE cte1
SET cte1.RandomNumber = cte2.RandomNumber
FROM cte cte1
JOIN (SELECT first, last, max(rnk) as MaxRnk FROM cte GROUP BY first, last) a 
ON a.first = cte1.first and a.last = cte1.last and cte1.rnk = 1
JOIN cte cte2 on cte1.first = cte2.first and cte1.last = cte2.last and cte2.rnk = a.maxrnk
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2012+, you can use `FIRST_VALUE()`:

```
with toupdate as (
      select c.*,
             first_value(randomnumber) over (partition by first, last order by id desc) as last_randomnumber
      from customer c
     )
update toupdate
    set randomnumber = last_randomnumber
    where randomnumber <> last_randomnumber;
```

The logic (in the `where`) is slightly more complicated if the random number can take on `NULL` values.

In earlier versions, you can do essentially the same thing using `outer apply`:

```
with toupdate as (
      select c.*, clast.randomnumber as last_randomnumber
      from customer c outer apply
           (select top 1 c2.*
            from customer c2
            where c2.first = c.first and c2.last = c.last 
            order by id desc
           ) clast
     )
update toupdate
    set randomnumber = last_randomnumber
    where randomnumber <> last_randomnumber;
```